# How to set the width of image view in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have tried many ways to do, but it doesn't work. And I want to align image view to left as well. After I changed the width of image, the relative layout will be changed automatically too. How to prevent that happens?

```
                TextView txtview=new TextView(this);
                ImageView imgview=new ImageView(this);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 250);

                params.setMargins(10,topMargin,10,20);
                txtview.setPadding(10,5,15,5);
                txtview.setText("Quiz: " + dbtitle);
                txtview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                txtview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_view);
                txtview.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END);
                txtview.setTextSize(18);
                txtview.setWidth(1000);
                txtview.setHeight(200);
                txtview.setLayoutParams(params);
                relativeLayout.addView(txtview);


                imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo1);
                imgview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                imgview.setLayoutParams(params);
                relativeLayout.addView(imgview);
```

Comment: change TextView txtview=new TextView(this) and ImageView imgview=new ImageView(this); to TextView txtview=findViewById(R.id...... etc. Should work

Comment: Because I am generating this dynamically under the for loop. Is there any others way to do it?

Comment: You can set dynamic width by adding below
`imgview.getLayoutParams().width = 200;`

Also for Left alignment, you can try below code

`params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;`